# python list to format and replace data

Tags: python, python-3.6

Requesting data from a website returns a list which looks like this.

```
[
     "https://site1.com/:hash",
     "https://site2.com/:hash",
     "https://site3.com/:hash",
     "https://site4.com/:hash",
     "https://site5.com/:hash"
]
```

I'm trying to loop over the list and replace the **:hash** with my a variable that equals **cats**. The extra formatting from the list along with the extra punctuation and the search/replace has me stumped. Any additional help would be greatly appreciated.

### Final Result Requested

```
https://site1.com/cats
https://site2.com/cats
https://site3.com/cats
https://site4.com/cats
https://site5.com/cats
```

### So far I have the following

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import requests
gw_path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ipfs/public-gateway-checker/master/gateways.json'

r = requests.get(gw_path)
text = r.text
for item in text:
   mod = item.replace(':hash', 'cats')
   print(mod)
```

.

Comment: what have you tried/researched so far?

Comment: You should be using `r.json()`, not `r.text`.

Answer (score 0):

If `a` is the initial list, use **list comprehension**:

```
a = ["https://site1.com/:hash",
      "https://site2.com/:hash",
      "https://site3.com/:hash",
      "https://site4.com/:hash",
      "https://site5.com/:hash"]

modified_a = [i.replace(':hash', 'cats') for i in a]

modified_a
['https://site1.com/cats',
 'https://site2.com/cats',
 'https://site3.com/cats',
 'https://site4.com/cats',
 'https://site5.com/cats']
```

And:

```
print "[%s]" % (','.join(modified_a)

[https://site1.com/cats,https://site2.com/cats,https://site3.com/cats,https://site4.com/cats,https://site5.com/cats]
```